# Scheduling SSRS with parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

Currently, I have a report on SSRS ( SQLServer 2008R2) and accept a invoice number as a parameter. The report will generate the information related to this invoice in 1 report. So, 1 invoice 1 report. If I need to generate 2 invoices, I need to run twice.

I would like to schedule it and generate reports automatically once the invoice appears in the database and save the output as PDF for each in a unique file name.

Just wonder what's the best option for me to do it

1) Use SSIS. Create a For..Loop to execute a SQL statement to return all invoices that fulfills the criteria and then call SSRS report.

2) In SSRS, there's a subscribe option but I can't find any way I can pass in the parameter automatically and for multiple times. Or some configuration that I missed out ?

Hope you can provide me some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: You can also write windows service. Which will be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

both 1 and 2 would work.  To me, I think 2 is better.

> 2) In SSRS, there's a subscribe option but I can't find any way I can pass in the parameter automatically and for multiple times. Or some configuration that I missed out ?

I found this on Microsoft site which covers how to pass in parameter value to report.  Hope it is helpful.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166561(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The current solution database is part of a standard software and I can't create additional table in the database structure. This is to avoid the functionality still available if the software is upgraded.

Saw another method - Data Driven Subscription 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169972.aspx#bkmk_startwizard

but I am still trying to research whether the report will be executed a few times if I have a few invoices to be passed in. 

Also, if I schedule the report every 1 hour and will SSRS able to pass in all the invoices to the report. One at a time ? Thanks...

Comment: I think you can put in a custom query for your subscriber's data:

>Step 3 - Define a query to retrieve subscriber data
In the query pane, type the following query:
Select * from UserInfo
Specify a time-out of 30 seconds.
Click Validate, and then click Next.

Comment: So you can pull out the invoice number from your standardized database just for the input for invoice number.

I don't have the report server with me, but I think the other parameter like render format, write mode, file extension, etc can be a static value, so really, you just need to come up with the query and trial.

Comment: Thanks Herman, I'll give it a try. I think I am able to perform this step.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169972(v=sql.105).aspx

Just that, I need to have a flag to remove or filter those records that I have already printed to PDF.

Comment: since you said it is invoice, does your standardized database contains any date context (i.e. the date of the invoice generated?)

then you can always do something like this:

select invoiceNumber FROM invoice where invoiceDate < getdate and invoiceStatus = "New"

Comment: Yes, I can use the date but from I am looking from support perspective as well. In case the report failed to run from a duration, how easy it is for a tech support to regenerate each files. As part of the change control process, we cannot modify the programs/scripts directly once approved.

Looks like custom database with subscriber table could be an easier option. We just need to repopulate the table with invoices and that should be sufficient.

Comment: well, if you are talking about support perspective as well, option number 1 of SSIS with a small custom database containing invoice number, recipient and delivery status would suit your need.  The SSIS will save ping your SSRS, save the PDF format in unique names and mark the delivery status.

you can rerun the SSIS in case of failure.  SSIS allows you to have a bit more control of workflow.

Comment: ouch ... I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 STANDARD Edition. Unfortunately, Data Driven Subscription not supported.